# SwipeJS - jQueryMobile Issue

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, gallery

I'm trying building a mobile app using HTML5, PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

I'm trying to incorporate an image figure slide gallery using SwipeJS. It works fine just the way it is. But every time I try and place it within the "`<div data-role="page">`" within my jQuery Mobile html document, it doesn't show at all.

I think it has something to do with the jQuery Mobiles stylesheet? I'm not 100% sure. I'm pretty new to mobile developments.

```
<div data-role="page" class="page-overide" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed">

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="reverse slide">Back</a>
            <h1>Applications</h1>
        </div>


        <div data-role="content" data-theme="my-theme">
            <strong>Title</strong>

            <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;' class='swipe' data-theme='my-theme'>
                <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                    <div><b>0</b></div>
                    <div><b>1</b></div>
                    <div><b>2</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

 <script src='swipe.js'></script>
```

More here:

http://jsfiddle.net/oliverj777/G7UkU/

Thanks

----- UPDATE -----

If I comment out the `visibility: hidden;` within the `.swipe` of the style, I can now see all the image placements, but now they're all one on top of each other vertically?!?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying like this

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" data-role="page" data-position="fixed">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="reverse slide">Back</a>
                <h1>Applications</h1>
            </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="contentSlider">
        <div id='mySwipe' style='min-width:500px; margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
            <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                <div><b>1</b>
                </div>
                <div><b>2</b>
                </div>
                <div><b>3</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
            <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button>
            <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');


window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    continuous: true

});
```

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/G7UkU/20/embedded/result/)